# Slide content down when expanding collapsible

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, collapsable

I have a collapsible that will be dynamically populated. When I expand the collapsible, it overlaps my flot chart.[image]

Is there a way to slide the chart div down when the collapsible has been expanded? likewise when it's collapsed again(slide up)?

This is currently my setup:

```
<div id="main" data-role="page">
        <div id="header" data-role="header">
            <h1>Real Time Monitoring</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="parameters" data-role="collapsible" style="position: relative;width: auto; height: 100px;">
            <h3>Parameters</h3>
                <div id="divSensors" class="ui-grid-a">
                    <!-- dynamically generate checkboxes based on available sensors (c#) -->
                </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Div for flot graph -->
        <div id="chart-container" style="position: relative;">
            <!-- <label>LX Accel(g)</label> -->
            <div id="placeholder" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></div>
            <label">Time</label>
        </div>


        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>&copy;&nbsp;Test Test</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: This is probably a CSS issue. What are the `position` and `z-index` properties of these elements?

Comment: all the css is in there. I don't have an external file yet. I wanted to get it working frist then shift all the css to an external file so everything you see here has the css right there. I can;t seem to find the z-index. I've looked in the styles console but it doesn't show it. The styles that are applied in here don't mean anything because I was just testing to see if I could get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `position: relative` from the collapsible and chart container, and also remove `height: 100px;` from the chart container.

Comment: thank you kind sir. Do you mind giving a mini explanation as to why this works? Css has never been my strongest point

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp. By default position is static, which means objects are rendered in order and thus flow one after another. When you set it to relative, you broke that flow.